# Code First CTP4 Error Mapper

Tags: .net, code-first

Why my type always returns 0?

```
public class PartiesConfiguracao : EntityConfiguration<Parties>
{
    public PartiesConfiguracao()
    {
        MapHierarchy()
        .Case<Parties>(parties => new
        {
            PartiesID = parties.ID,
            ShipInstructionID = parties.ShipInstruction.ID,
            ContactID = parties.Contact.ID,
            parties.Name,
            Type = 0,
            parties.CNPJ,
            parties.Address
        })
        .Case<Shipper>(parties => new
        {
            Type = 1
        })
        .Case<Consignee>(parties => new
        {
            Type = 2
        })
        .Case<Notify>(parties => new
        {
            Type = 3
        })
        .Case<Forwarder>(parties => new
        {
            Type = 4
        })
        .ToTable("si_Parties");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*MapHierarchy* is related to CTP4 and has been removed in CTP5. No further support is provided. You should download and install CTP5 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d) and try using the new fluent API introduced in CTP5 for your TPH mapping.